# Pagination using multiple searcing criteria in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, codeigniter-pagination

Im trying to implement pagination using multiple searching criteria.
Supposed I Have student table. I also use pagination when the list of student displayed.
The pagination link is. `site_url . '/student/page/';` so I use `$config['uri_segment'] = 1`;
so the pagination link will be

```
<a href="http://mysite/index.php/student/page/0">1</a>
<a href="http://mysite/index.php/student/page/1">2</a>
```

and son.

After that I wanna search student data using 3 searching criteria implemented using textfield.

```
id  name    address.
```

user can search by id or name or address or combination of the three criteria. 
the url become

```
http://mysite/index.php/student/page/0
href=http://mysite/index.php/student/page/1
```

and son.

but  I use get method for searching.  and while trying to search using the search criteria field the url become

```
href="http://mysite/index.php/student/page/1?id=1&name=a&address=b
```

the problem occurred when I try create pagination based on criteria. because the pagination link have contain query string
i don't know how to create become

```
href="http://mysite/index.php/student/page/0?id=1&name=a&address=b
href="http://mysite/index.php/student/page/1?id=1&name=a&address=b
```

or do you have a best practice to solve this problem ?

---

Hi phill ....
I have try your suggestion.

```
$array = array('id' => '001', 'name' => 'a', 'address' => 'canada');
```

the url become
`id/001/name/a/address/canada`. I use `$this->uri->uri_to_assoc()` function to get key and value of the segment.

```
array (
    id => 001,
    name=>a,
    address=>canada
)
```

but while there some searching criteria that not included while searching. let say, the user only search by name and address. the array become
`$array = array('id' => '', 'name' => 'a', 'address' => 'canada');` and the url `id/name/a/address/canada`
the assoc array become

```
array (
    id => name,
    a=>address,
    canada=>
)
```

the assoc array is not disorganized again. so I can't get the right value of the assoc array.
I think i will set the identifier to the searching criteria if not included. supposed i put `#`.

```
if isset($_GET['id']) then
$id = '#'
else 
$id = $_GET['id']

$array = array('id' => $id, 'name' => 'a', 'address' => 'canada');
```

How about that ... ? or if there are another best practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that I would use $this->uri->uri_to_assoc():

> index.php/user/search/name/joe/location/UK/gender/male
>
> Using this function you can turn the
>   URI into an associative array with
>   this prototype:

```
[array]
(
    'name' => 'joe'
    'location' => 'UK'
    'gender' => 'male'
)
```

See the full documentation [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html).

You can still use page/1 as the first lot then have /name/whatever afterwards.

Comment: Hi ..., phil. I have try your suggestion. but I have some problem. I have edit my question. Hope you can check my question and give me some problem solving.

Thanks

Comment: Just make sure you dont put keys into the URL if they don't have a value.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy, we can create pagination with multiple and unlimited criteria. Read here http://dengkul.com/2010/07/08/codeigniter-pagination-with-multiple-unlimited-searching-criteria/